# Using Bootstrap column classes with divs of varying heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am setting up a seemingly easy layout using Bootstrap 3 with eight text divs, almost the same height but some slightly taller than others depending on screen width.

I'd like them to fit into three columns on desktop and shrink to two columns on smaller screens.

**What I've Tried**

- Setting each div to col-xs-6 and col-md-4. However, on desktop, the size of the div is causing gaps in the some 'cells'.
- Wrapping each set of three divs in a `.row` which fixes the problem on desktop but adds a new problem on mobile. (see code below)
- Adding a clearfix div that is visible-md but this does not solve the problem.

How can I make the following markup display in three even columns on desktops and two even columns (with no gaps) on mobile devices?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#bond">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#buffa">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#ebert">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#gale">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Accounting Officer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#kleinman">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">General Counsel & Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#scarpati">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Compliance Officer</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#selinger">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#tareke">text text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to hopefully be more clear for those answering the question, please let me know if I've deviated from the original intent of your post

Answer (score 1):

The row class is used to create groups of columns, but isn't really needed. You can get rid of it to acheive the look you want.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/qPDrnEvZI3)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#bond">text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>                                
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#buffa">text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#ebert">text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#gale">text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">Chief Accounting Officer</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#kleinman">text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">General Counsel &amp; Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#scarpati">text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">Chief Compliance Officer</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#selinger">text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <h4><a href="#tareke">text text text</a></h4>
    <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#bond">text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#buffa">text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#ebert">text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#gale">text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">Chief Accounting Officer</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#kleinman">text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">General Counsel &amp; Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#scarpati">text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">Chief Compliance Officer</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#selinger">text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <h4><a href="#tareke">text text text</a></h4>
  <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Although it's not visible on the bootply, this causes gaps in the columns on desktop where some divs are taller.

Comment: Would that be due to the content inside of them causing the div to become taller?

Comment: I believe I see what you mean, but I have a feeling that's more of an issue with going from an odd number of columns per row to an even number.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? It's a bit hacky since I'm overriding col-xs-6. Feel free to make that a custom class instead.

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
    .col-xs-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }    
}
```

```html
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#bond">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#buffa">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#ebert">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#gale">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Accounting Officer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#kleinman">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">General Counsel & Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#scarpati">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Compliance Officer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#selinger">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#tareke">text text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nicole j. Patten** Take a look at the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87rny4fc/)**, to see if works for you... for what you are looking for here.
I left the old code at the top and my new code displays at the bottom.
On the top section it shows the two caps and the lower section it all lines up fine.
This also resizes fine too.
Because of the font-size the the way the text stacks on very small screen size... (< 320px) I use a media breakpoint to help with a few classes here.

Take a look and see if this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.space {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;  
}
.space-1 {  
  margin-top: 5%;
  height:10px;  
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: blueviolet  
}     
.info {
   height:90px; 
   margin-top: 2%;
   margin-bottom:2%;
} 
   
@media(max-width:320px) {
.info {
   height:70px; 
   margin-top: 1%;
   margin-bottom:1%; 
} 
p {
  font-size: .8em;
} 
h4 {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}     
}      
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container col-lg-12 space"></div>
    
    
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#bond">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#buffa">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#ebert">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#gale">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Accounting Officer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#kleinman">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">General Counsel & Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#scarpati">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Compliance Officer</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#selinger">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <h4><a href="#tareke">text text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
</div>           
</div> <!--end container-->
 
    
    
    
    
<div class="container col-lg-12 space-1"></div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#bond">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#buffa">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#ebert">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#gale">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Accounting Officer</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#kleinman">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">General Counsel & Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#scarpati">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Chief Compliance Officer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#selinger">text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 info">
        <h4><a href="#tareke">text text text</a></h4>
        <p class="subtitle">Managing Director</p>
    </div>
           
</div> <!--end container-->
    
<div class="container col-lg-12 space-1"></div>    
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```